# How can I debug a shell script file containing an executable command in pycharm?

Tags: python, shell, debugging, pycharm

I have a  shell script file that contains the necessary parameters to run
the Python file. I can only run this script with the `green button on the top right` of pycharm, but when I select the debug option, it
quickly goes out of debug mode. This script file contains the `python 3 command`.

How can I debug code with this script?

[image: Relevant photo]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please check out: [Why Shouldn’t I Post Code in an Image Format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13991219)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking PyCharm to debug two different programming languages at the same time. Instead, create a Debug configuration for your Python script with all the necessary parameters: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html

This might take a moment to set up but you will then be able to set breakpoints and debug your Python script.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
The problem was solved according to your instructions.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Feel free to upvote and/or mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Comment: @JanWilamowski , I have a .sh script which execute a python file main.py, I'd like to set breakpoints both in the .sh and in .py and 
Debug with a Shell Script configuration under PyCharm. Do you mean it is not possible and I have to debug separately ? Thank you:)

Comment: @RémyHosseinkhanBoucher I'm not sure if that's possible but  you could ask a new question about that